# How to generate stake registration certificate from extended stake address verification key using cardano-cli

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-address

Is there a way for `cardano-cli` to generate stake registration certificate using the extended stake address verification key (`stake_xvk`) that was generated from `cardano-address` CLI?

Steps to generate extended stake address verification key:

```
 cardano-address recovery-phrase generate --size 15 > phrase.prv
 cardano-address key from-recovery-phrase Shelley < phrase.prv > root.xsk
 cardano-address key child 1852H/1815H/0H/2/0 < root.xsk | cardano-address key public --with-chain-code > stake.xvk
```

Now I have extended stake address verification key `stake.xvk`.

From here, I want to generate stake registration certificate using cardano-cli like so:

```
cardano-cli stake-address registration-certificate \
--staking-verification-key-file stake.vkey \
--out-file stake.cert
```

But this doesn't work because the content of `--staking-verification-key-file` is much different that of `stake_xvk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert to `cardano-cli` compatible key files, start with the `cardano-address` formatted **stake.xsk** signing key file, then work your way down using the following commands.

```
cardano-address recovery-phrase generate --size 15 > phrase.prv
cardano-address key from-recovery-phrase Shelley < phrase.prv > root.xsk
cardano-address key child 1852H/1815H/0H/2/0 < root.xsk > stake.xsk
cardano-cli key convert-cardano-address-key --shelley-stake-key --signing-key-file stake_0_0.xsk --out-file stake.skey
```

You will then need to generate the non-extended (i.e. without the chain code) **stake.vkey** file which the `cardano-cli` accepts.

```
cardano-address key public --without-chain-code < stake.xsk | tee stake.vk
VKEYHEX=$( cat stake.vk | bech32)
cat << EOF > stake.vkey
{
    "type": "StakeVerificationKeyShelley_ed25519",
    "description": "",
    "cborHex": "5820$VKEYHEX"
}
EOF
```

Now that you have the `cardano-cli` compatible **stake.skey** and **stake.vkey**, generate the stake registration certificate you can use the same command as before

```
cardano-cli stake-address registration-certificate --stake-verification-key-file stake.vkey --out-file stake.cert
```

You should then be able to sign the transaction using the extended **stake.skey** file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Sorry if my question was a misleading but I need to find a way to generate certificates just with the verification key. This is because my application is separated into two components; ones generating unsigned transactions and others signing it.

Comment: With the commands I posted you will have the stake.skey and stake.vkey. To generate the certificate you just need to run the same command as before, i.e. `cardano-cli stake-address registration-certificate --stake-verification-key-file stake.vkey --out-file stake.cert`. I will edit the answer for completeness' sake :)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to generate the stake.vkey, the process is the following:

```
cardano-address key child 1852H/1815H/0H/2/0 < root.xsk > stake.xprv
cardano-address address delegation $(cat stake.xprv | cardano-address key public | tee stake.xpub)

SESKEY=$( cat stake.xprv | bech32 | cut -b -128 )\$( cat stake.xpub | bech32)

cat << EOF > stake.skey
{
    "type": "StakeExtendedSigningKeyShelley_ed25519_bip32",
    "description": "",
    "cborHex": "5880\$SESKEY"
}
EOF

cardano-cli shelley key verification-key --signing-key-file stake.skey --verification-key-file stake.evkey
cardano-cli shelley key non-extended-key --extended-verification-key-file stake.evkey --verification-key-file stake.vkey
```

Once you have the stake.vkey, you can generate the staking certificate with the command that you listed:

```
cardano-cli stake-address registration-certificate \
--staking-verification-key-file stake.vkey \
--out-file stake.cert
```

Credits to [ilap](https://gist.github.com/ilap/3fd57e39520c90f084d25b0ef2b96894) (I took the commands from his script)

Comment: Okay it worked, but instead of addding `5880` at the beginning, I've added `5840` instead. Adding `5580` threw the following exception:

```
Command failed: key non-extended-key  Error: ShelleyStake.vkey: TextEnvelope decode error: DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure "VerificationKey StakeExtendedKey" (DeserialiseFailure 2 "end of input")
```

Do you know what this number means? cardano-cli that I'm currently using is:
cardano-cli 1.33.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 814df2c146f5d56f8c35a681fe75e85b905aed5d

Comment: Okay my friend did a little bit of research and this is what 5580 means.
The cborhex here contains of 4 parts:
1. prefix 5880 - bytestring of 128 bytes
2. signing key (64 bytes)
3. verification key (32 bytes)
4. chain code (32 bytes)
Rule for prefixes:
  - CBOR-encoded bytestring (which is what the 58 identifies)
  - size (80 means 128 bytes, whereas 40 means 64 bytes, 20 means 32 bytes)

Comment: Well done, this will be helpful also for other people. Happy to help :-)